# How to purge available updates information in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, updates, apt

I have `Ubuntu 18.04.2` installed, but had to temporarily add a repo from the next (`cosmic`) release to install a couple of packages. Now after I've commented out the cosmic repo in my `sources.list`, did `apt update` - after each reboot my system suggests me to update a lot of packages (though it fails to download them because of the commented out repo). How do I get rid of this suggestions? Tried to google around, but failed to find.

Comment: Are the packages and their dependencies for which you added the cosmic repo still installed?  If so, you need to keep the cosmic repo to keep those packages current.  It won't do anything else with the repo.  But as long as the packages are installed, it will look for the repo to keep them maintained.  If for some reason you don't want those packages to be updated, you can select to ignore updates for them when the updates appear in the list (typically via right click).

Answer (score 0):

Search for installed obsolete packages, either locally installed or obsolete because their source repository is disabled. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install aptitude  
aptitude search '?narrow(?installed, ~Oppa | ~o)'
```

or install Synaptic package manager with `sudo apt install synaptic` and click on the *Status* button marked by the mouse cursor in the left panel and select *Installed (local or obsolete)*.

[image]